# How Can I get fields of entity in hook_entity_presave

Tags: entities

According [hook_entity_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7) I can perform an act before entity save or update.

I want to get a list of fields used in that entity. Is there any way to figure out the fields of that entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this method you have access all fields used in your content types.
[entity_get_info Doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7) and [field_info_instances Doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) gave me ideas on how can I got them.

```
function custommodule_entity_presave($entity,$type) {
    $allFields=field_info_instances('node');
    $savedFields=$allFields[$entity->type];
}
```